# hpricot problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hpricot

I am trying to use hpricot in a controller. I would like to pass this value to a html.erb page so I can display it on the screen

So I wrote this:

```
session[:allcars] = (doc/"td.car_title/text()")
```

but this gives an error

when I tried this:

```
puts (doc/"td.car_title/text()")
```

this printed the cars into the console.

So I can't understand what I'm doing wrong :S

Thanks

Comment: What class is the result of (doc/"td.car_title/text()")? Maybe its something different than session is able to store. Maybe to_s will help.

Comment: but then i cannot distinguish between one item and the other :/

Comment: What is the error you're seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to pass variables from a controller to a view is to use a member variable.

```
@allcars = (doc/"td.car_title/text()")
```

Then in your html.rb page, get the value using `@allcars`.